# What is the 'Slight Return' In Voodoo Child referring to?

Tags: song-title, jimi-hendrix

I have realised that I have been listening to Jimi Hendrix's music since infancy and I never knew what the 'Slight Return' in parentheses in the song 'Voodoo Child (Slight Return)' is referring to? Does anybody mind illuminating me?

Comment: If someone asked why Beethoven's piano sonata 14 was titles "quasi una fantasia", would it get migrated?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - It should, it's a question about a piece of music, not about the practice of music.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the album Electric Ladyland, there's a track called Voodoo Child, around 15 minutes long. There's a sort of reprise later, called Voodoo Child (Slight Return), which is far shorter, at around 5 minutes. This is the more commonly aired version. As it's so much shorter than the original, there is apparently only a short (slight) return to it.